# Div percentages of a 100% don't fit in one line

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one has the width of 20% and the other is 80%, they should fit in one line because they both make up 100% but they don't for some reason.

I made sure I added the box model fix, box-sizing I mean, but it still doesn't fit. I tried playing around with margins, borders, paddings, but no luck so far. I have no idea what the problem is. I measured the pixels they make up by seeing the percentages of each div, and for some reason they make up more than a 100%, but why? I set their width to 20% and 80%, why would they be more than their parent container's total width?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* The Box Model Fix */
}

#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #193e7a;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 900px;
}

#title h1 {
  /* font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive; */
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  margin: 180px 0 0 20%;
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#title h2 {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  /* font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive; */
  margin: 0 0 0 20%;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-small {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #a3b4d1;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-width: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.col-small p {
  padding: 10px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-wide {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #a3b4d1;
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 480px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <header>
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="col-small">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </div>
    <div class="col-wide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r9vgxeyu/1/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: In your CSS it says `.col-small` has `width: 25%;`